# ArgumentParser: Only accept optional argument if first argument is a certain value

Tags: python

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("first_arg")
parser.add_argument("--second_arg")
```

I want to say that `second_arg` should only be accepted when `first_arg` takes a certain value , for example "A". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('firstvalue')
parser_a.add_argument('bar', choices='A')
parser_a.add_argument("--second_arg")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be simplest just to do this manually after parsing args:

```
import sys
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.first_arg != 'A' and args.second_arg: # second_arg 'store_true'
    sys.exit("script.py: error: some error message")
```

Or if `second_arg` isn't `store_true`, set `second_arg`'s `default` to `None`. Then the conditional is:

```
if args.first_arg != 'A' and args.second_arg is not None:
```